# How to sort a HashSet in C#?

Tags: c#

```
data analyst - 0.9999998 
data officer - 0.7673618 
data specialist - 0.7630831 
data manager - 0.7497395 
data coordinator - 0.7493373 
data scientist - 0.7462178
```

The values of my HashSet looks like above.
The float followed after `-` is transferred to String.
I want to just take those float values and sort this HashSet
based on the string-ified float value.

I know that the float can be retrieved by doing,

`item[i].Split(' ')[2]`

But how can I sort it based on this?

Comment: Keep it in a list then.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495770/sort-a-hashset-net-3-5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Hashset .Net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495770/sort-a-hashset-net-3-5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) implements the [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. So you can use the [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) method to sort your items:

```
var orderedSet = mySet.OrderBy(item => 
    float.Parse(item.Split(new string[]{" - "}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]));
```

Comment: This gives me a FormatException on `float`. Any idea?

Comment: [2] is the minus, not the decimal number

Comment: @Dawn17 You wrote in your question "I know that the float can be retrieved by doing, `item[i].Split(' ')[2]`" and this answer assumed that you were right. You weren't, hence the error. You'd probably need to split on `" - "` instead of `' '`.

Comment: Yep, gotta split by " - ". Just updated my answer. Try it again!